# FullCalendar Scheduler Scroll to current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullcalendar

I'm using the Scheduler with a 1 year view.  So I can see every day from Jan 1 to Dec 31 by scrolling horizontally.

Minor issue is that the horizontal scroll is always at the initial position (all the way left) so it always display Jan 1.  Is there a way for it to scroll to the current date or month on the initial load?

I was looking into scrolling through it with jQuery by finding the current date and `ScrollLeft` to the element.  But it seems that the header is separate from the scrolling container so not sure how that would work.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @fr0sty Yea, I just wrote some calculation to get the offset and set it.  Let me post it.

Comment: @fr0sty I posted the answer.  Seems like someone else found another solution so you can try that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version 2.6.1

```
eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
    var viewStartDate;
    if (view.name == 'yearView') {
        viewStartDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    }
    else if (view.name == 'twoMonthView' || view.name == 'oneMonthView') {
        viewStartDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1);
    }

    if (view.name == 'oneWeekView') {
        $('.fc-body .fc-time-area .fc-scrollpane').children('div').scrollLeft(4 * 12 * (moment().weekday() - 1) * view.options.slotWidth);
    }
    else {
        var dateDiff = (new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) - viewStartDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

        $('.fc-body .fc-time-area .fc-scrollpane').children('div').scrollLeft(Math.round(dateDiff) * view.options.slotWidth);
    }
}
```

This is the main part in version 2.6.1

```
var dateDiff = (new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) - viewStartDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

$('.fc-body .fc-time-area .fc-scrollpane').children('div').scrollLeft(Math.round(dateDiff) * view.options.slotWidth);
```

In Version 3.0+ the structure of the HTML is different.  The element to scroll on has changed.

```
$('.fc-body .fc-time-area .fc-scroller-clip .fc-scroller').scrollLeft(Math.round(dateDiff) * view.options.slotWidth)
```

Can probably reduce it down to

```
$('.fc-scroller').scrollLeft(Math.round(dateDiff) * view.options.slotWidth)
```

Comment: Nothing is happening for me here, my view name is timelineYear so i changed that. Using version 3.1.0. I can see that the dateDiff value changes if i manually change the viewStartDate value. But it seems that the last line is not finding anything

Comment: @fr0sty You have jQuery and Moment.js installed? I'm using version 2.6.1, not sure if the structure changed.  But the `div` inside the `.fc-scrollpane` is what scrolls.  The size of the cells are fixed `view.options.slotWidth` is say `80px`.  I just calculate the number of days from the start (Jan 1) to today and multiple by the width (i.e. 44 days * 80px = 3520px) and scroll left by that amount of pixels.

Comment: yes, but it looks like they changed all the classes in the 3.1.0 version. Can't find the right class to use the scrollLeft on.

Comment: @fr0sty You can inspect the HTML in the browser (Inspect Element in Chrome) to find out the structure.  I looked it up and it's `$('.fc-scroller').scrollLeft(200)`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it again. I placed an alert after your line of code. The scheduler scrolls nicely to the position. But when i close the alert box it scrolls back to January 1st again. Seems like there is another process that is being called after the eventAfterAllRender process.

Comment: @fr0sty If that's the case, you can put the code outside the fullcalendar initialization.  Check the scroll position, if it's not Jan 1 and it's set to 0 then scrollLeft.  You can check every 1 second for 10 seconds to make sure.

Comment: For version 3+, it should be `$('.fc-body .fc-time-area .fc-scroller-clip .fc-scroller').scrollLeft(Math.round(dateDiff) * view.slotWidth)` . The value `view.options.slotWidth` from earlier versions is not set anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem just yesterday and found the following solution (working with fullCalendar 2.6.1):

```
// Scroll the calendar to a specific event
scrollToEvent: function(event) {
    // Get the "scroller" divs for header and content
    var headerScroller = $('.fc-time-area.fc-widget-header > .fc-scrollpane > div');
    var contentScroller = $('.fc-time-area.fc-widget-content > .fc-scrollpane > div');

    // Get the destination date
    // For some reason event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') will be formatted 
    // as 'YYYY-MM-DDAHH:mm:ss', hence the "replace" hack.
    // Maybe I have to dig more into moment js...
    var dateSelector = 'th[data-date="' + event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss').replace('A', 'T') + '"]';
    var date = $(dateSelector).last()[0];

    // Scroll to date
    headerScroller.scrollLeft(date.offsetLeft);
    contentScroller.scrollLeft(date.offsetLeft);

    // To scroll vertically to a specific resource (if any)...
    // Get the destination resource
    var resourceSelector = 'tr[data-resource-id="' + event.resourceId + '"]';
    var resource = $(resourceSelector).last()[0];

    // Scroll to resource
    contentScroller.scrollTop(resource.offsetTop);
}
```

I have called the above function from "eventAfterAllRender" function of FullCalendar, using a flag to check for the first rendering only. Don't know if there's a better way...

Simpler code to just scroll to date:

```
scrollToDate: function(date) {
    // Get the "scroller" (no need to distinguish between header and content so get both)
    var scroller = $('.fc-time-area > .fc-scrollpane > div');

    // Get the destination date
    var selector = 'th[data-date="' + date.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') + '"]';
    var date = $(selector).last()[0];

    // Scroll to date
    scroller.scrollLeft(date.offsetLeft);
}
```

Hope this helps (this is my first post on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Can't get your examples to work, with the simple code nothing happens. Even after editing a bit.
<code>eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
                            var scroller = $('.fc-time-area > .fc-scrollpane > div');

                            // Get the destination date
                            var selector = 'th[data-date="2017-02-12"]';
                            var date = $(selector).last()[0];

                            // Scroll to date
                            scroller.scrollLeft(date.offsetLeft);
    
                        }</code>