# gotoDate() not working on FullCalendar in timeline view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using the timeline view of FullCalendar v5 and `@fullcalendar/react` and I want my clanedar to automatically to scroll to today.  When I call `.gotoDate()` it doesn't do anything.

Here is my calendar code:

```
const calendarRef = useRef();

const getCalendarApi = () => {
    const {current} = calendarRef;
    return current?.getApi();
};

return (
    <FullCalendar
        ref={calendarRef}
        timeZone="local"
        initialView="resourceTimelineMonth"
        ...
    />
);
```

Here is the code I'm using to call `gotoDate()`:

```
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
        const calendarApi = getCalendarApi();
        calendarApi.gotoDate(new Date());
    }}
>
    test
</button>
```

When I click the "test" button, nothing happens.  I checked and `calendarApi.gotoDate()` is a valid function it's just not doing anything.  Any ideas why this isn't working?

#### UPDATE #1:

I also tried adding `initialDate="2021-03-23"` to the `<FullCalendar />` but it also doesn't do anything

#### UPDATE #2:

I tried adding `validRange` and it worked in that it scrolled to the start date but now it's not showing me any events before the start date.

```
return (
    <FullCalendar
        ref={calendarRef}
        timeZone="local"
        initialView="resourceTimelineMonth"
        validRange={()=> {
            return {
                start: "2021-03-20",
                end: "2021-03-31"
            };
        }}
        ...
    />
);
```

Comment: Have you tried passing it a string inside of the `new Date()`? Does it work then?

Comment: @maxshuty, do you mean `calendarApi.gotoDate("2021-03-23");`?  I just tried it and it also didn't work. :(

Comment: `gotoDate()` changes the view, if necessary. If the date requested is already in the current view, it doesn't do anything. initialDate is the same - if the date is already on the default view, it won't move it along.

Comment: FullCalendar doesn't support this directly. Don't know whether any of these still work in v5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810788/fullcalendar-scheduler-scroll-to-current-date

Comment: You might need to request a feature too to get it fully supported in future, or vote on one that's already there: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: Your other option of course is to use a shorter timeframe for the view - e.g. week - by default so it's more likely the current date is already visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
let cell = document.querySelector('.fc-day-today');

cell.scrollIntoView();
```

There seems to still be an issue with the margin overlapping and then showing the scrollbar in the header sometimes, however, since the cell for the date is already rendered, you can just call element.scrollIntoView();

If you want the cell centered, you can call:

```
cell.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'auto',
            block: 'center',
            inline: 'center'
        });
```

Hope this helps. I'm still looking at how to fix the margin scrollbar issue, but this should get you most of the way there farely easily.